# What ever happened to the methylphenidate synthesiser and his family?

Tags: chemistry, biology, death, psychology

Leandro Panizzon [1](http://serendip.brynmawr.edu/bb/neuro/neuro05/web1/a1jordan.html) [2](http://www.swissinfo.ch/eng/ritalin-use-is-on-the-rise/29155620) [3](http://inhn.org/drugs/methylphenidate.html) synthesised methylphenidate or something like that back in 1944. Ritalin is named after his wife Rita.

He doesn't seem to have a Wikipedia page or anything. What happened to him? I'm guessing he's dead now. When did he die? Any heirs or relatives?

Comment: According to [geboren.de](http://geboren.am/person/leandro-panizzon), he died in 2003 but I have no idea how reliable this site is, or where do they take their informations from.

Comment: Centuries ago, that's history.  Yesterday, that's not history.  1944?  Is that "history"?  Our guidelines do not say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can see how Leandro Panizzon and his wife Marguerite looked in their old age.

[image]

After, as was usual at that time, testing his invention himself with no apparent result, he let his wife have a try (who suffered from low blood pressure). Methylphenidate apparently improved her tennis capabilities. Today it is used not only as medicine, in cases of ADHS ([which seems to be a fabricated illness](https://nebadonien.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/beichte-auf-dem-sterbebett-ich-habe-gelogen-und-betrogen/)), but also as a drug (called Rita).

In 1950 Panizzon together with Max Hartmann obtained a US patent (number 2507631) for an improved manufacturing method of methylphenidate. In 1954 methylphenidate came on the market. In 2014 Novartis had a turnover of 492 million US-Dollar with Ritalin. In 2013 338 kg Ritalin were sold compared to 23 kg in 1998.

Panizzon got vice-director of his Swiss company Ciba (today Novartis)

He died in 2003.

The couple had four children.

Sources: https://adhspedia.de/wiki/Leandro_Panizzon
http://www.unternehmerzeitung.ch/ausserdem/schweizer-pioniere/panizzons-wunderpille/